# Gack on Apex Jobs page - Status Detail column for certain jobs

Tags: asynchronous, gack

Wondering why my Queueable failed with:

```
Salesforce System Error: 1380510393-83097 (1289245132) (1289245132)
```

as shown on the Apex Jobs page

No email sent to Apex Exception email address; no limits exception displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Heap was breached. Normally, a Limits error will display on the Apex Jobs page.

If you turn debug on, and can reproduce the transaction, you'll see Heap breach in debug; or, call Support and have them look in logs for the Gack and time period in question.

See [Known Issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IYDNQA4) which explains why no such Limits exception message appears

```
"java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean" still occurs after a heap limit exceeded event

Apex , API

Last updated 23 days ago ·Reference W-3177604 ·Reported By 48 users

IN REVIEW

Summary
"java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean" still occurs after a heap limit exceeded event.

- Actual Result
Internal Server Error caused by "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean" occurs.

- Expected Result
Heap limit exceeded exception instead Internal Server Error should occur.
```